# Python. How can I sum a list with strings and integers?

Tags: python, list

how can i sum the integers in a list like this.

```
studlist = ['mario;90;80', 'denis;80;70', 'fabio;60;70']
```

I have tried this way but the professor is asking to do it specifically like the list above.

```
score= [90, 80, 80, 70 , 60, 70]
name=['mario', 'denis', 'fabio']
print('the total score of',name[0], 'is' , score[0]+score[1])
print('the total score of',name[1], 'is' , score[2]+score[3])
print('the total score of',name[2], 'is' ,  score[4]+score[5])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how you can do it. If I properly understood your question.

```
studlist = ['mario;90;80', 'denis;80;70', 'fabio;60;70']

for name_score in studlist:
    name_score_list = name_score.split(";")
    print('the total score of',name_score_list[0], 'is' , int(name_score_list[1])+int(name_score_list[2]))
```

Comment: Yes! that exactly what I needed. Thank you!!

Comment: @Jwy04 Welcome.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `split` to handle the strings:

```py
studlist = ['mario;90;80', 'denis;80;70', 'fabio;60;70']

for student in studlist:
    name, *scores = student.split(';')
    print(f"The total score of {name} is {sum(int(s) for s in scores)}")

# The total score of mario is 170
# The total score of denis is 150
# The total score of fabio is 130
```